# Docker with Knex and PG: cannot run migration or get data from database but can connect via GUI only

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, knex.js

I'm building a project with Node, Knex, PostgreSQL and I'm Dockerizing my project.
The main issue I have I'm unable to run the migration and also to get the data from the DB using Knex.
What I can do is use DB GUI such as Tableplus to connect to the DB.

You can find my project here:
[Repo of the project](https://github.com/Jakub41/testingKnexObjectionJS)

All I read online is not working for me as

- use the service name \ container name -> not working :(
- use full postgres url as `postgresql://root:password@postgres/dbname'`-> not working :(
- IP address as 0.0.0.0 not working
- IP address as 127.0.0.1 I can use only to run migrations/seeds but not to use the DB as GET/POST
- I can use docker.internal.host but then cannot do the migration then

I'm getting always this error

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pokedex-db-postgres`

I have no more ideas what is wrong so I'm sharing my configuration hoping someone will help me to understand

Docker file

```
# Builder
FROM node:17.3
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/code/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/code
WORKDIR /home/node/code
COPY package*.json ./
USER node
RUN yarn install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 8800

ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "run", "dev" ]
```

Docker compose

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    container_name: pokedex-backend-node
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      postgresDB:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - '8800:8800'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/code
  postgresDB:
    container_name: pokedex-db-postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: postgres:14.1
    networks:
      backend-database: null
      postgres-pgadmin: null
    expose:
      - '5343:5432'
    ports:
      - '5343:5432'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./volumes/postgres-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'pg_isready -U root']
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 4s
      retries: 3
  db-admin-pgadmin:
    container_name: pokedex-dbadmin-pgadmin
    depends_on:
      postgresDB:
        condition: service_started
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    networks:
      postgres-pgadmin: null
    ports:
      - '8900:80'
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
networks:
  backend-database: {}
  postgres-pgadmin: {}
```

Knex configuration

```
const development = {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: 'pokedex-db-postgres',
    port: config.POSTGRES_PORT,
    database: config.POSTGRES_DB,
    user: config.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: config.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  },
  pool: {
    min: 5,
    max: 50,
    createTimeoutMillis: 3000,
    acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    reapIntervalMillis: 1000,
    createRetryIntervalMillis: 100,
    afterCreate: function (conn, done) {
      conn.query('SELECT 1;', function (err) {
        if (err) {
          log.error('Connection to DB failed %s', err);
        }
        done(err, conn);
      });
    },
  },
  debug: dev ? true : false,
  migrations: {
    directory: './src/database/migrations',
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: './src/database/seeds',
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've defined the networks for pgadmin and postgres but didn't for the node app it explains why your node app doesn't see the other containers `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pokedex-db-postgres`

Comment: Unfortunately, even if I remove all the networks which should use the default bridge is not working so cannot accept this answer :(